# How to request additional google oauth2 scope?

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I'm using google oauth 2 for registrations.

While registration i'm asking these two scopes.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

and I've successfully stored oauth2 tokens like refresh token in the database.

Some of my users interested in inviting their friends.

So I would like to request additional scope to access that user's contacts.
This is the scope to access contacts

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
```

Now is there a way to request additional scope without forcing the user to logout and authorize again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
You cannot.
Users will have to re-login.

Comment: Is this still the case?